# WCF REST hosted in IIS 6 , not able to consume it on client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, iis-6

I have hosted my WCF REST Service in IIS6. But when I try to consume any method, it gives me an error 400.

However when I use the same url in IE, the desired response is achieved. How come I can't consume it in my client while I can hit it directly in IE.

Following is the Client code :

```
string xmlInputValue = XMLUtility<string>.GetDataContractXml("Testing", null);

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream";
xmlInputValue = string.Empty;
byte[] buf = new byte[0x10000];
wc.UploadString(new Uri(@"http://localhost/FileUpload/UploadData/PingTest/?123"), "POST", "4567");
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick question, why are you setting Content-type as "application/octet-stream"? are you sure service binding is expecting the same content-type. Anyways, I'd capture Fiddler trace (using fiddler tool: http://fiddler2.com) for IE (success scenario) and check how request is sent by IE which is accepted by service and compare with request sent by client application.

HTH,
Amit

Comment: Hey Amit, Thanks for the response. I have done that. It doesnt come up in the fiddler.

Comment: Fiddler won't show requests to Localhost. Use your machine name.

Comment: Fiddler says that end points are not defined
<body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p>Endpoint not found.</p>
    </div>
  </body>

Comment: Could you please post/share client configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. While using IIS for hosting the service, endpoint address should be blank